# How can I create an action that is available only to me

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home, google-assistant-sdk

I've tried now several times understanding if it is possible, and if yes how, to create custom actions that are available just for me on a Google Home device. I have a working Dialog Flow agent that works well in the Dialog Flow simulator. It used to work in the Google Assistant simulator and I could enable it for one hour, but now that doesn't work either.

I would be happy using IFTTT if it had webhook responses instead of just fixed responses...

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: I kind of got it working with a test version. It seems to be working indefinetly. However, the assistant always responds by saying "Alright. Getting the test version of Your App" before actually activating...

Answer (score 1):

There is not a good way to have private actions for a given user. The only way to do it is to enable testing for a given project. Then all devices using your account should be able to "talk to my test app" and communicate to your webhook. However, this test may end after a few days.